# Python 3.7 crashes down during locustio load test

Tags: python, locust

I use Locustio version 0.8.1 (https://locust.io/) for load testing on MacOS machine. It works fine with python 2, python 3.6.6, but when I try to use it with python 3.7 python crashes down. If I start load test with only one parallel user python 3.7 works fine, but with at least 2 users it crashes down.

```
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.5 (17F77)
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.0 (3.7.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [2997]
Responsible:           Python [4258]
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

I checked it also using a very basic load test, locustfile.py:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    @task(1)
    def get_smth(self):
        self.client.get(url="/")


class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 0
    max_wait = 0
```

Command for staring Locust:

```
locust --host=http://example.com
```

Using Web monitor on local host I specify "Number of users to simulate", "Hatch rate" to start swarming. And after it starts swarming python 3.7 crashes down.

Any advice ?

Comment: Locust currently is only tested against 3.6 - https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/tox.ini#L2 - it's possible there are issues we need to fix before it can work with 3.7.

Comment: claiming something "crashes down" is vague and unhelpful.  You should report this to the locust project's issue tracke, but give exact details of what that actually means, including any stacktraces or error messages you encounter.